# Nodejs and mysql database timezone issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, timezone

am having a bad time with the timezone of my server

am using nodejs as backend and express routes for services

i changed the time for the server with the correct one using:-

> dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

and i checked the server time and seems good

am using

> data

to get the current time and it's correct for my country (Saudi Arabia)

the problem is when the record created in the database still give me the wrong time within a delay of 3 hours !!!!

so the database time and server is correct, how come the record created with wrong time ?

Answer (score 1):

The time that's being saved in the db is in UTC. Since the Saudi Arabia time is UTC + 3h, you see a 3 hours gap in the time. I advise you to keep the db timezone in UTC as it is, and whenever you retrieve a record, add the 3 hours to the time to convert it to Saudi time.
Similarly, if you want to search by time, subtract 3 ours from your time that you want to search, thereby converting it to UTC time.

Comment: thank sir for the quick response, so is there any way to handle it automatically, so any record will be created with +3 hour, because am doing complex calc and i need to save the correct time without adding +3 for the records (application layer)

Comment: You can always change the default mysql timezone. But I'll strongly advise against it since it limits your application's scalability.

Comment: However if you still want to do it, use something like SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'

Answer (score 0):

I remember this fixed a bug regarding time zones.

```
var timeZoneDifference=(this.date.getTimezoneOffset()-dateFuture.getTimezoneOffset())/60;
```

Comment: thnak you sir , please advice me how to use this code , i want to fix the timezone from application layer , so i want pure data without any problem , thnx

Comment: The bug was that for my 24-hour gaming boss timer, when Daylight Savings changed over, the GMT offset was different than PST for 8 hours leading to incorrect calculations. As I'd found the original buggy code online being shared to the world, I just want to add this fix.